# Can we make an app that uses the camera and make a call at the same time?

Tags: ios

I know I can't record a video while I'm on my phone in general and that if the capability existed or could exist that it would be a feature/option.

Are there apps that do this and if it can be done can someone help me get started code wise?

EDIT
Because there seems to be some confusion as to what I'm asking, I will clarify:

Are we able to launch phone calls using the iPhone regular calling feature and use the iPhone regular movie creating feature (the video camera) at the same time in an APP - as we know it can't be done generally.

Comment: If by call you mean through the carrier through telecom, no you can't. You would have to implement your own VoIP (Voice over IP) service. Are you talking about a Skype type interfacing?

Comment: Xcode is just an IDE. You're asking iOS ?

Comment: iOS yes - in general, so iPhone just doesn't allow it's camera to launch while a phone call is in process? It's as simple as that? Can't we break that with code?

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no.  You can't use Apple's built-in camera and phone to do it.  But, obviously there are many apps (i.e. Skype and others) that use both camera and voice features in their VoIP implementations.  So, it would take a custom camera and VoIP to accomplish this.